# Using Lets Encrypt SSL certificates with crossbar WAMP router (0.13)

Tags: android, websocket, lets-encrypt, crossbar, wamp-protocol

A certificate has been generated from Let's Encrypt and installed onto an existing (working) crossbar server as follows (and as [the documentation suggests](https://crossbar.io/docs/Secure-WebSocket-and-HTTPS/)):

```
"endpoint": {
    "type": "tcp",
    "port": 8089,
    "tls": {
      "key": "../ssl/key.pem",
      "certificate": "../ssl/cert.pem"
    }
  },
```

When connecting via Java (I am sure the result would have been similar if differently worded in other APIs) the result is:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Having determined this could be due to requiring [Let's Encrypt's intermediate certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/#intermediate-certificates) that was linked like this:

```
"endpoint": {
    "type": "tcp",
    "port": 8089,
    "tls": {
      "key": "../ssl/key.pem",
      "certificate": "../ssl/cert.pem",
      "ca_certificates": [
           "../ssl/intermediate.cert.pem"
       ],
    }
  },
```

Unfortunately this also does not work, resulting in a handshake error (I didn't note down the exact wording).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging further into the documentation I found [this example](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar-examples/blob/4aa51915da2360e022ed2afa4e54e4aad2ae5185/demos/_demo_launcher/.crossbar/config.json#L130) which explicitly references a lets encrypt intermediate but has a different name for the key parameter:

```
"chain_certificates": [
     "lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem"
],
```

Trying this resulted in the same issue (handshake failure)

I then tried the following:

- Concatenate the certificate file with Let's Encrypt's intermediate
- Revert to the initial configuration just using the certificate and key parameters

So basically this:

```
  "tls": {
      "key": "../ssl/key.pem",
      "certificate": "../ssl/cert-plus-intermediate.pem"
    }
```

After restarting the server again (you'll need to restart each time you change SSL settings) the connection established correctly. Note also that once you have a working configuration you should ensure the key file can only be read by a trusted user on the system, ideally just whichever user crossbar will run as (`chmod 600 key.pem`)